# React Native pass data in all screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I would like to have access to an object in all my screens. The user object which I get back through firebase. I get the obejct from the method onAuthStateChanged. How can I get the user in app.js and get access to it in all screens?

thats the code in the root app:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import { globalStyles, styles } from './styles/global';
import BottomTabScreen, { RootStackScreen } from './navigation/Index';
import DrawerContent from './navigation/DrawerContent';

import { on_auth_state_changed } from './firebase/Api';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {

  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isAuthenticationReady: false,
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    on_auth_state_changed(authStateChanged);
  }, [])

  function authStateChanged(user) {
    setAuthState({
      ...authState,
      isAuthenticated: !!user,
      isAuthenticationReady: true,
      isLoadingComplete: true,
    })
  }

  if (!authState.isLoadingComplete) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#80c904' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={globalStyles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {(authState.isAuthenticated) ?
          <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={BottomTabScreen} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
          :
          <RootStackScreen />
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). There are also other options like Redux or any state management library, but for your needs, Context API is more than enough.